# Checkstyle - Avoid Inline Conditionals - allow if on one line?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'd like to configure Checkstyle to allow inline conditionals without flagging them as long as the whole inline conditional is on one line.

For example,

```
cellValue = profiles.get(keyTmp) ? CONCAT_CODE + value : value;
```

would be fine, but as soon as it wraps, I want to flag it up.

The justification for flagging them in the first place is that inline conditionals are hard to read, according to the Checkstyle javadoc, and I agree mostly with the exception that they are easy enough to read when they don't wrap.

The configuration options appear to be limited though. Is there any out there with black belt checkstyle-fu who knows a way?

Comment: Would the point-and-clickers voting down the question please consider moving their hands across to their keyboards and leaving a constructive comment? Or even better, an answer!

Comment: Not possible. You'll have to write a [custom check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html) ...